# Enable cloudwatch logs for kinesis firehose cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-kinesis-firehose, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am trying to catch Cloudwatch logs for my firehose to find any errors when sending data to `S3` destination. I created a cloudformation template with logging details

```json
"CloudWatchLoggingOptions" : {
    "Enabled" : "true",
    "LogGroupName": "/aws/firehose/firehose-dev", -->firehose-dev is my firehosedeliverystream name 
    "LogStreamName" : "s3logs"
},
```

I have given necesary IAM permission to firehose for creating `loggroupname` and `streamname`.

```json
{
    "Sid": "",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
    ]
}
```

When i triggered the template i didnt find any of the loggroupname and streamname is created in cloudwatch logs.

But when we give same IAM permissions to `AWS::Lambda` resource it will automatically create a loggroupname(i.e.`/aws/lambda/mylambdaname`) and send the logs to the that group. But why this scenario is not working for firehose ?

**As a Workaround**

I am manually creating `AWS::Logs::LogGroup` resource with name as `/aws/firehose/firehose-dev` and `AWS::Logs::LogStream` resource with name as `s3logs`.

---

> And also firehose will create a loggroup name and logstream name
> automatically, if we configure the firehose deliverystream using
> console.

Can't firehose create loggroup name and logstream name automatically like aws lambda do when configured through cloudformation?

Thanks
Any help is appreciated

Comment: How did it go? The issue still persists?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its resource dependent. Some resources will create the log group for you, some not. Sometimes console does create them in the background. When you use CloudFormation, usually you have to do everything yourself.

In case of Firehose you can create the `AWS::Logs::LogGroup` and `AWS::Logs::LogStream` resources in CloudFormation. For example (yaml):

```yaml
MyFirehoseLogGroup:
  Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
  Properties: 
    RetentionInDays: 1
        
MyFirehoseLogStream:      
  Type: AWS::Logs::LogStream
  Properties: 
    LogGroupName: !Ref MyFirehoseLogGroup
```

Then when you define your `AWS::KinesisFirehose::DeliveryStream`, you could reference them:

```yaml
CloudWatchLoggingOptions: 
  Enabled: true
  LogGroupName: !Ref MyFirehoseLogGroup
  LogStreamName: !Ref MyFirehoseLogStream
```